# how to display vAxis in google chart in time format?

Tags: google-visualization

I would like to create a line chart that show lap times in vertical axis, i.e:

```
lap1: 1:14.9
lap2: 1:14.0
lap3: 1:12.8
lap4: 1:13.6
```

The customer would like to have a time format (instead of plain numbers) in vertical axis. Is it possible to configure google charts to draw this?

Comment: @GeorgeMillo Alas, no.

Comment: I posted a question myself and got a usable answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19781363/format-a-time-as-hoursminutes-on-a-google-charts-y-axis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is old, but...

I had a similar issue and posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19781363/format-a-time-as-hoursminutes-on-a-google-charts-y-axis).

As far as I'm aware there's no way to do this through `vAxis.format`, but you can achieve the effect you want with `vAxis.ticks`. For example, if the "time" value you're passing to your chart is just a number in seconds, you could create a `ticks` object like this:

```
vAxis: { ticks: [{v:0, f:"0:00.0"}, {v:30, f:"0:30.0"}, {v:60, f:"1:00:0"}] }
```

The catch is that the v-axis will *always* display *all* ticks that you pass it. So if you don't know in advance what the range of the v-axis will be, you might have to dynamically generate the `ticks` object by looping over your data and determining what the highest and lowest times are.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14440231/google-charts-vertical-axis-in-whole-numbers/14472345#14472345) has information on how to dynamically generate min and max axis values.