# Google Visualization API: How to format numeric axis labels to time duration?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Is there a way to format numeric axis labels to time duration, like Avg. Visit Duration Chart on Google Analytics?

e.g. 160 seconds is formatted to 00:02:40 on axis

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Date', 'Avg. Visit Duration'],
    [new Date(2012, 9, 1),  233062],
    [new Date(2012, 9, 2),  210645],
    [new Date(2012, 9, 3),  253180],
    [new Date(2012, 9, 4),  296351],    
    ...
]);
```

A screenshot of visit duration chart: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGVtD.png

Answer (score 0):

See my answer to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695246/how-to-display-vaxis-in-google-chart-in-time-format/19803417#19803417)...

> As far as I'm aware there's no way to do this through vAxis.format,
>   but you can achieve the effect you want with vAxis.ticks. For example,
>   if the "time" value you're passing to your chart is just a number in
>   seconds, you could create a ticks object like this:
>
> ```
> vAxis: { ticks: [{v:0, f:"0:00.0"}, {v:30, f:"0:30.0"}, {v:60, f:"1:00:0"}] }
> ```
>
> The catch is that the v-axis will always display all ticks that you
>   pass it. So if you don't know in advance what the range of the v-axis
>   will be, you might have to dynamically generate the ticks object by
>   looping over your data and determining what the highest and lowest
>   times are.