# Setting vAxis format in Google Line Chart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

How to set the vAxis value format in google Line Chart in order to not get multiple lines with same value? Let's say I have lines with values: 1.5 1.0 0.5 and 0, after I set the format to '#', I got 0, 0, 1, 1...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14440231/google-charts-vertical-axis-in-whole-numbers/14472345#14472345)

Copy-pasted answer:

> If you just want numbers to *display* as whole numbers, then it's
>   easy:
>
> ```
> function drawVisualization() {
>   // Create and populate the data table.
>   var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
>     ['x', 'Cats', 'Blanket 1', 'Blanket 2'],
>     ['A',   1,       1,           0.5],
>     ['B',   2,       0.5,         1],
>     ['C',   4,       1,           0.5],
>     ['D',   8,       0.5,         1],
>     ['E',   7,       1,           0.5],
>     ['F',   7,       0.5,         1],
>     ['G',   8,       1,           0.5],
>     ['H',   4,       0.5,         1],
>     ['I',   2,       1,           0.5],
>     ['J',   3.5,     0.5,         1],
>     ['K',   3,       1,           0.5],
>     ['L',   3.5,     0.5,         1],
>     ['M',   1,       1,           0.5],
>     ['N',   1,       0.5,         1]
>   ]);
>
>   // Create and draw the visualization.
>   new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
>       draw(data, {curveType: "function",
>                   width: 500, height: 400,
>                   vAxis: {maxValue: 10, format: '0'}}
>           );
> }
> ```
>
> If you go to [google playground][1] you will note that the axis labels
>   are 0, 2.5, 5, 7.5, 10. By adding the format: '0' to the vAxis, it
>   will display only whole numbers, so my labels become 0, 3, 5, 8, 10.
>   But obviously this is not ideal since 8 displays as being halfway
>   between 5 and 10, which it isn't, because the number is actually 7.5
>   and just being rounded.
>
> Your ability to change the axis scale/labels is restricted. And to do
>   what you're asking would take a special bit of javascript to create an
>   appropriate scale and number of gridlines to prevent breaking things
>   down in to funky numbers.
>
> Basically, you want to make sure that your maximum and minimum values,
>   and number of gridlines, allow for easy division such that you will
>   only get whole numbers. To do that, you need to create some funky new
>   logic. Here is some sample code that will allow you to get an
>   appropriate min/max axis value:
>
> ```
> // Take the Max/Min of all data values in all graphs
> var totalMax = 345;
> var totalMin = -123;
>
> // Figure out the largest number (positive or negative)
> var biggestNumber = Math.max(Math.abs(totalMax),Math.abs(totalMin));
>
> // Round to an exponent of 10 appropriate for the biggest number
> var roundingExp = Math.floor(Math.log(biggestNumber) / Math.LN10);
> var roundingDec = Math.pow(10,roundingExp);
>
> // Round your max and min to the nearest exponent of 10
> var newMax = Math.ceil(totalMax/roundingDec)*roundingDec;
> var newMin = Math.floor(totalMin/roundingDec)*roundingDec;
>
> // Determine the range of your values
> var range = newMax - newMin;
>
> // Define the number of gridlines (default 5)
> var gridlines = 5;
>
> // Determine an appropriate gap between gridlines
> var interval = range / (gridlines - 1);
>
> // Round that interval up to the exponent of 10
> var newInterval = Math.ceil(interval/roundingDec)*roundingDec;
>
> // Re-round your max and min to the new interval
> var finalMax = Math.ceil(totalMax/newInterval)*newInterval;
> var finalMin = Math.floor(totalMin/newInterval)*newInterval;
> ```
>
> There are a couple issues here (unfortunately). The first is that I am
>   using the number of gridlines to determine the min/max values -- you
>   want to figure out how many gridlines you should have to use nice
>   whole numbers. The easiest way to do this, I think, would be as
>   follows (pseudo-code only):
>
> ```
> // Take the Max/Min of all data values in all graphs
> var totalMax = 3;
> var totalMin = -1;
>
> // Figure out the largest number (positive or negative)
> var biggestNumber = Math.max(Math.abs(totalMax),Math.abs(totalMin));
>
> // Round to an exponent of 10 appropriate for the biggest number
> var roundingExp = Math.floor(Math.log(biggestNumber) / Math.LN10);
> var roundingDec = Math.pow(10,roundingExp);
>
> // Round your max and min to the nearest exponent of 10
> var newMax = Math.ceil(totalMax/roundingDec)*roundingDec;
> var newMin = Math.floor(totalMin/roundingDec)*roundingDec;
>
> // Determine the range of your values
> var range = newMax - newMin;
>
> // Calculate the best factor for number of gridlines (2-5 gridlines)
> // If the range of numbers divided by 2 or 5 is a whole number, use it
> for (var i = 2; i <= 5; ++i) {
>     if ( Math.round(range/i) = range/i) {
>         var gridlines = i
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Then you set the gridlines option (vAxis.gridlines) to the above
>   variable, and your max to newMax, and your min to newMin. That should
>   give you whole number axis labels.
>
> Note: if your numbers are really small then the above function may not
>   work. The function is also not tested so please check it against some
>   examples on your own time and let me know if it doesn't work properly.
>
> [1]:
>   http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#line_chart

Comment: Thank you, I will test it as soon as I can, this seems to be really interesting