# Control Y Axis in google line graph

Tags: google-visualization, linegraph

I have created a line graph using the google chart, I have inserted the image of the chart with this question. You may see that Y axis values are in created by 2, I would like to increase the Y Axis values by 1, is there any way to do so.

Image line http://imagebin.org/260899

Answer (score 1):

I think that playing with parameter `gridlines:{count}` is right way to solve your problem, e.g.

```js
                    hAxis: {
                             minValue: 0.00,
                             maxValue: 10.00
                     },
                     vAxis: {
                             minValue: 0.00,
                             maxValue:8.00,
                             baseline:4.00,
                             viewWindowMode:'explicit',
                             viewWindow:
                             {
                                max:8.00,
                                min:0.00
                             },
                             gridlines:{count:9}
                     }
```

Comment: If your values change, you can create a javascript function that will determine the appropriate amount of gridlines using math. [Here is an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14440231/google-charts-vertical-axis-in-whole-numbers/14472345#14472345) of a function that will make sure the axis values are all whole numbers.