# Google Annotated Time Line chart (y-axis) scale

Tags: google-visualization, annotatedtimeline

I am using Google Annotated Time Line chart, I want the scale in the Y-axis to show integer numbers only, not fractions(if min is 0 and max is between 1,4).

I have tried to do it using max and min but there are cases where a line exceeds  the  max, so is there any method to force this chart to display only integer numbers. I have read the options in documentation many times but still no luck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14440231/google-charts-vertical-axis-in-whole-numbers/14472345#14472345).

Comment: but this vAxis: {maxValue: 10, format: '0'}} which is included in the answer is not valid in annotated time line chart,i have already tried to use it but seems to have no effect. but thanks anyway for your answer.

Comment: you're right -- I didn't realize it was annotated timeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the max of your data, and set the max of the chart based on that value, or 5, whichever is higher:

```
var max = 5;
for (var i = 1; i < data.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
    if (data.getColumnType(i) == 'number') {
        var range = data.getColumnRange(i);
        max = Math.max(max, range.max);
    }
}
```

Then in the chart's options, set `max: max`.

Comment: This will have very odd behavior with negative numbers which may not work properly. It is much better to calculate both min and max in a function as explained in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14440231/google-charts-vertical-axis-in-whole-numbers/14472345#14472345)

Comment: The OP specified that the min was 0, so this is safe in this instance.  I agree that calculating both is generally a better idea.

Comment: thanks alot this worked for me ,but how you know the function getNumberOfColumns ,i cannot find it in the documentaion.??

Comment: It is referenced in the DataTable documentation: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable_getNumberOfColumns

Comment: i mean in annotated time line documentation,how it a function for datatable and worked in annotated time line?thanks anyway you are awesome!!!

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question.  Could you clarify it?

Comment: Sorry @asgallant, you're spot on there.