# Y Axis in Google Charts increments in "General 1, General 2" etc - Java Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-visualization, google-docs, google-sheets-api

I have a problem with my dashboard in Google Charts. Currently everything works except that the column chart displays a string rather than an integer on the Y axis.

I find the documentation on the Google charts pages very hard to understand, so I apologize if there are mistakes in my code, or if there's a simpler way I could have done things.

[image: screenshot]

My JS Fiddle is as shown here: https://jsfiddle.net/hm7q5peg/6/

```
    google.load('visualization', '1.0', {
    'packages': ['corechart','table', 'controls']
});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawDashboard);

function drawDashboard() {
    // Using the jsapi, it's better to set the url
    // for the spreadsheet, then use setQuery() to
    // define the query that will provide your data.
    var url = '//docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=1FOVmfesx7ATNe8qjWjkU2GbjBCBZxL0BRswJv6rcGPs&usp=drive_web&gid=1324373577';

    var query = new google.visualization.Query(url);
    query.setQuery('select B,C where B <> ""');

    // Send the query with a callback function
    query.send(handleQueryResponse);
}

function handleQueryResponse(response) {
    // Called when the query response is returned.
    if (response.isError()) {
        alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
        return;
    }

    var data = response.getDataTable();

    var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
    document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));

    // Create a range slider, passing some options
    var donutRangeSlider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        'controlType': 'NumberRangeFilter',
            'containerId': 'filter_div',
            'options': {
            'filterColumnLabel': 'Number Attended'
        }
    });


    // Create a pie chart, passing some options
    var pieChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        'chartType': 'PieChart',
            'containerId': 'chart_div',
            'options': {
            'width': 300,
                'height': 300,
                'pieSliceText': 'value',
                'legend': 'right'
        }
    });

        //define a table
    var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        'chartType': 'Table',
        'containerId': 'table_div',
        'options': {
            'width':'300px'
        }
    });

    //define the column chart
    var columnChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        'chartType': 'ColumnChart',
        'containerId' : 'column_div',
    });

    // Establish dependencies, declaring that 'filter' drives 'pieChart',
    // so that the pie chart will only display entries that are let through
    // given the chosen slider range.
    dashboard.bind(donutRangeSlider, [pieChart, table, columnChart]);

    // Draw the dashboard.
    dashboard.draw(data);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you haven't done so already, have a look at the [ColumnChart Configuration Options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#Configuration_Options) to see what you have to play with. By specifying a numeric format for the vertical axis, you will get numbers. Unfortunately, without a [bunch of additional code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14440231/google-charts-vertical-axis-in-whole-numbers), gViz will decide that you must want to see fractions, even though your data is all integers.

[image: screenshot]

[Updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hm7q5peg/9/).

```
//define the column chart
var columnChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    'chartType': 'ColumnChart',
    'options' : {
        'hAxis' : { 'title' : 'Student Name' },
        'legend' : {position: 'none' },
        'vAxis' : {format: 'short',
                   title: 'Number Attended'}
     },
    'containerId' : 'column_div',
});
```

Comment: You sir are you everywhere aha, after all your guidance at least i managed to implement some functionality on my own. Albeit i still failed in the end, all this stuff just wont sink in to my head, as mentioned i really do not like the documentation its really unclear to me. Anyways  Thank you once again for your time sir.

Comment: I question what you're looking for in the documentation, that would lead you to call it unclear. I suspect that what you're in need of is not so much API documentation, but guidance in the form of instructional videos or tutorials. Check [this search](https://www.google.ca/webhp?#q=google+visualization+api+tutorial). Of course, the API assumes pre-existing competence with HTML and Javascript, so it's a challenging place to start. Oh, hey... you have enough rep to upvote now!

Comment: when i look at documentations i want to be able to see clearly where and how to structure your code for example i have been using Parse for part of this project, developing an Android app. Bare in mind i have never coded in android before nor used Parse but because the documentation was perfect and easy to understand i managed to created a attendance system. I guess each language has their own way of displaying information....... aha and yes i shall fulfil my duty and see what i can do with the points i got now