# Google line chart only full steps / ticks

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I'm looking for a way to set the line chart steps to only full number steps like 1,2,3,4,5.....

Currently it looks like this:

[image]

These are my options. I've searched a lot but can't find the solution.

```
let options = {
    vAxis: {
        title: "Tests",
        textStyle:{
            color: "#222222"
        },
        viewWindowMode: "explicit",
        viewWindow: {
            min: 0,
        }
    },
};
```

In an older library I used before I had following setting enabled to only allow 1 step sizes:

```
"ticks": {
    "beginAtZero": true,
    "stepSize": 1
}
```

Maybe Google has this too but I can't find anything about this..

**Update**

`format: 0` ends up with this result:

[image]

This is really strange, because we have 3 ones and two zeros now.

**Update 2**

This is an example of my situation with no data given. I can't get it running here but on my system it works that way:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load("current", {"packages":["line"]});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  
  function drawChart() {
 let data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
 
 data.addColumn("string", "Months");
 data.addColumn("number", "Tests");
  
  data.addRows([
    ["January",  0],
  ["February",  0],
  ["March",  0],
  ["April",  0],
  ["May",  0],
  ["June",  0],
  ["July",  0],
  ["August",  0],
  ["September",  0],
  ["October",  0],
  ["November",  0],
  ["December",  0]
    ]);
    
    let options = {
        chart: {
            title: "Statistics of tests",
            subtitle: "per Month"
   },
   titleTextStyle: {
            fontSize: 15
        },
   vAxis: {
       title: "Tests",
     viewWindowMode: "explicit",
     viewWindow: {
       min: 0,
     }
  }
    
    function initChart() {
  let chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById("chart"));
     chart.draw(data, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(options));
 }
 window.onload = initChart();
 window.onresize = initChart;
}
</script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
vAxis: {
  format: 0
}
```

Should do what you're looking for

Edit: Did some more searching and it seems like you could have some trouble simply applying this - This question has been asked before though, [here is the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14440231/google-charts-vertical-axis-in-whole-numbers/14472345#14472345)

Comment: The problem will be gone until there are data but without data, the format looks strange with format: 0

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `ticks` option.

```
vAxis: {
  format: '0',
  ticks: [0, 1]  // <-- a grid line will be drawn for each tick added
}
```

if you want to add ticks dynamically,
you can use data table method --> `getColumnRange(colIndex)`
this method returns an object with the `min` & `max` values of the column provided

then you can build the ticks in a loop...

```
var range = data.getColumnRange(1);
var ticks = [];
for (var i = 0; i <= range.max; i++) {
  ticks.push(i);
}
```

then in the options...

```
vAxis: {
  format: '0',
  ticks: ticks
}
```

Comment: This works great if there are given data. If it's empty, the chart looks like in my update above.

Comment: there shouldn't be any repeating axis labels, how, or are you creating the ticks?

Comment: when you say empty, the data table has no rows?

Comment: When it's empty, there are some default rows, just one like I showed in my question.

Comment: will you please share a sample of the data?

Comment: thanks, now I see the problem. you're using a _material_ line chart (`google.chart.Line`) vs. a _classic_ line chart (`google.visualization.LineChart`) -- there are several options, including `ticks`, that are not supported by _material_ charts. see [Tracking Issue for Material Chart Feature Parity](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143) -- are you willing to switch to a _classic_ line chart?

Comment: So if this is the problem, I'll stay at the material design one and living with the wrong ticks. Good to know, thanks a lot mate!