# Format a time as hours:minutes on a Google Charts y-axis

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have a Google Chart where the y-axis is measured in minutes.

How can I format the y-axis so the labels display the time in a format like **`2hrs40`**, or **`2:40`**, or something similar? I don't want to display the time in raw minutes, and I don't want to display it as a decimal like "1.5" for 90 minutes.

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart) tells me to use the [ICU Pattern Set](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classDecimalFormat.html#_details), but I can't figure it out from that page.

Is this possible? And if I can't format the time like this directly, is there a way I can "hack" the chart after the fact by changing the `<svg>` element using Javascript?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The formatting options don't allow you to do that.  You can, however, use the `vAxis.ticks` option to manually specify the values to use for the tick marks and the strings you want to use to represent the values.  The `vAxis.ticks` option takes an array of objects, where each object has `v` (value) and `f` (formatted value - what gets displayed on the chart) properties.  Something like this should work:

```
vAxis: {
    ticks: [{v: 0, f: '0:00'}, {v: 30, f: '0:30'}, {v: 60, f: '1:00'}, {v: 90, f: '1:30'}]
}
```

Comment: This works. As I don't know in advance what the range of the y-axis will be, I had to generate the `ticks` object dynamically, which is a little bit hacky, but no matter. Thanks!

Comment: I realise this post is quite old now, but @GMA, if you happen still have the (even hacky) code you wrote, if you could post it up, that would be great. I have similar issue to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Google lets you do that....I'm doing this to show data like "5 mins". In your options do this:

```
            vAxis: {
            format: 'm \'mins\''
        },
```